# Open and close Windows 8 touch keyboard tabtip under desktop

Tags: .net, windows, keyboard

I need to close the tabtip keyboard from a program under Windows 8 (desktop winform .NET).
I found to open it when need, run TabTip.exe to display the Windows 8 Touch keyboard, but i can't close it when i need!
I tried to kill the process with process.kill but it doesn't work, someone has an idea how to do it?

Regards
Jean-claude

Comment: Did you find out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Nothing found, sorry. I'm developing a WinForm keyboard which is similar to the one in Windows 8, i used the Microsoft keyboard sample.

Comment: I figured it out and answered my own question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148740/how-to-close-textinputpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below- Replace Osk with TabTip

Public Class Form1

```
Private oskProcess As Process

Private Sub openButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles openButton.Click
    If Me.oskProcess Is Nothing OrElse Me.oskProcess.HasExited Then
        If Me.oskProcess IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.oskProcess.HasExited Then
            Me.oskProcess.Close()
        End If

        Me.oskProcess = Process.Start("osk")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub closeButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles closeButton.Click
    If Me.oskProcess IsNot Nothing Then
        If Not Me.oskProcess.HasExited Then
            'CloseMainWindow would generally be preferred but the OSK doesn't respond.
            Me.oskProcess.Kill()
        End If

        Me.oskProcess.Close()
        Me.oskProcess = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 3):

Tabtip.exe opens, then spawns two process before closing again.  So the process.kill command does not work because the originating process is already closed.

This looks through all the open processes and closes anything tabtip related.

```
For Each pkiller As Process In Process.GetProcesses
      If String.Compare(pkiller.ProcessName, "tabtip", True) = 0 Then
          pkiller.Kill()
      End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered an undocumented COM interface for controlling the on-screen keyboard. Check my other answer for the details https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921638/332528