# How to close TextInputPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am porting a WPF application to run on a Windows 8 tablet.

I want to make a TextInputPanel appear when a textbox gets focus and disappear when it looses focus.

Making it appear is no problem but I can't seem to make it close.

I have tried both Kill and CloseMainWindow on the process but get an InvalidOperationException - Cannot process request because the process has exited.

I tried SendMessage but nothing.

Any ideas?

Some WinForm test code follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VirtualKeyboard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
        static uint WM_QUIT = 0x0012;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Process _keyboardProcess;

        private void Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _keyboardProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe");
        }

        private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // tried all these
            //SendMessage(_keyboardProcess.Handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            //SendMessage(_keyboardProcess.Handle, WM_QUIT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            //_keyboardProcess.Kill();
            //_keyboardProcess.CloseMainWindow();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: _keyboardProcess = null maybe

Comment: Killing the process should definitely kill the window. Have you attached a debugger and verified that `Close_Click()` is called when you expect?

Comment: I updated the question slightly - Close_Click is called but the process has already exited before I try and Kill it. Yet the keyboard is still there. Perhaps it spawns another process.

Comment: That was it. TabTip spawned another 2 processes and closed the first one. I iterated through all running processes and closed the one with a process name of TabTip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, TabTip immediately spawns 2 other processes then exits the calling process.

Iterate through all open processes and close one called TabTip. This will close both processes.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VirtualKeyboard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe");
        }

        private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach(Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == "TabTip")
                {
                    process.Kill();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: process.Kill() may result in Access Denied