# how to kill tabtip process after starting it

Tags: vb.net, process, kill

I can start tabtip (virtual keyboad) in my program but for some reason I can't kill it.

This is my code:

```
Private tabtipProcess As Process

Private Sub t_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    tabtipProcess = Process.Start("tabtip")
End Sub

Private Sub t_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    tabtipProcess.Kill()
End Sub
```

On the line `tabtipProcess.Kill()` I get this error:

> Cannot process request because the process (5312) has exited.

Comment: Please do try to format your question properly. Refer to the _"How to Format"_ box that shows up when writing your question. I fixed it for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close TextInputPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148740/how-to-close-textinputpanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'v got it:

```
For Each pkiller As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If String.Compare(pkiller.ProcessName, "tabtip", True) = 0 Then
            pkiller.Kill()
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You could also use `Process.GetProcessesByName` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.0) more details.